# Installing GeoIP on Redhat x86_64 es5 with no success?

Tags: installation, redhat, yum, geoip

I am trying to install GeoIP on my Redhat x86_64 es5 but im getting errors. The packages im trying to install is:

GeoIP-1.4.7-0.2.20090931cvs.rhel5.x86_64.rpm

GeoIP-devel-1.4.7-0.2.20090931cvs.rhel5.x86_64.rpm

And I get this warning: "warning: GeoIP-devel-1.4.7-0.2.20090931cvs.rhel5.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID b56a8bac". I have done a google search and people say that I can install it with "yum install GeoIP GeoIP-devel GeoIP-data", but running that gives me a no package available notice.

Is there a kind soul out there that could assist? If you cant, please up vote this so that someone that might will see it!

Comment: Guide for anyone in the same situation:

Comment: Get EPEL installed. Then "yum install GeoIP-devel GeoIP-data", then go to WHM, Module Installer, Click on Pecl, search for GeoIP and install. Then install the C library by following this simply guide http://forum.tufat.com/showthread.php?t=60851

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have previously used this for the same packages.. (EPEL)

```
rpm -Uvh http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/x86_64/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
```

To search for correct packages try..

```
yum search geoip
```

Then simply installing should be as you already have been answered..

**Note:** when installing the EPEL.. accept the GPG key ( so you dont need to do it on every install)

How do I know that a package is a EPEL package????

All EPEL packages are signed with the EPEL gpg-key. The public key with id 217521F6 is part of the epel-release package; yum will ask you to import it the first time you install a EPEL package.

Comment: Thank you for this helpful respond. Could you please elaborate on exactly how I accept the GPG key?

Comment: It should be a yes or no question ???
are you not offered this choice?

Comment: Just to note, these instructions helped me do a yum installation of GeoIP, cheers buddy.

Comment: Yes I did get a Yes/No option, but it didnt save it thought. But that is fine, the only thing I got left to install is memcache so choosing Yes another time should not hurt ;)

Comment: Great. so the problem is solved??? :D ..

Glad to help...

Comment: Yes it is. Pain in the ass to install the GeoIP to be honest, but all good now. The EPEL installation helped!

Answer (score 2):

Those are warnings; receiving them does not indicate that the install failed.

Anyways, it's in [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL).

Comment: Sorry could you elaborate on EPEL?

Comment: Also, why didnt "yum install GeoIP GeoIP-devel GeoIP-data" work?

Comment: Have you read the article behind the link yet?

Comment: Because it's not in the RHEL repositories.

Comment: I am trying to make sense of it. Appreciate that I am not that experienced with this, I have mainly followed tutorials to setup my server so my knowledge is limited. Could you please enlight me with what I would need to do?

Comment: First you click on "How to use EPEL". Then you follow the directions. Then you can use yum to install packages from it.

Comment: And if you dont mind, where can I see which versions of the geoip-devel I have installed? How do I uninstall one of them? I installed an early version of it and it is saying that it is conflicting with the new one.

Comment: `yum list somepackage` will show you all packages with that name, installed or available. `yum remove somepackage` will remove a package and all other packages that depend on it.

Comment: Just to note, these instructions helped me do a yum installation of GeoIP, cheers buddy.